# Call requires API level 12 (current min is 9): android.os.Bundle#getString

Tags: android

How do I make the following work for a API less than 12?

`sourceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sourceId", "defaultKey");`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
    sourceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sourceId", "defaultKey");
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getString(java.lang.String)), which was added in API 1

```
public String getString (String key)
```

> Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key or a null value is explicitly associated with the key.
>   **Parameters**
>   *key* a String, or null
>   **Returns**
>   a String value, or null

It simply doesn't have a default value, but you can check if it's `null` manually

```
sourceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sourceId");
if (sourceId == null)
    sourceId = "defaultKey";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sourceId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sourceId");
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(sourceId)){
   sourceId = "defaultKey";
}else{

}
```

Documentation for TextUtils http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html